# Executing batches of commands using redis cli

Tags: redis

I have a long text file of redis commands that I need to execute using the redis command line interface:

e.g.

```
DEL 9012012
DEL 1212
DEL 12214314
```

etc.

I can't seem to figure out a way to enter the commands faster than one at a time.  There are several hundred thousands lines, so I don't want to just pile them all into one DEL command, they also don't need to all run at once.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

the following code works for me with redis 2.4.7 on mac

```
./redis-cli < temp.redisCmds
```

Does that satisfy your requirements? Or are you looking to see if there's a way to programmatically do it faster?

Comment: If authenticated, then use `redis-cli -a <password> < temp.redisCmds`

Comment: In Windows PowerShell: `Get-Content cmds.txt | redis-cli`

Comment: When I change this like to `redis-cli --pipe < temp.redisCmds`, it gets even faster. See the answer from @zucaritask.

Answer (score 71):

If you don't want to make a file, use `echo` and `\n`

```
echo "DEL 9012012\nDEL 1212" | redis-cli
```

Comment: Worked like a charm for me!

Comment: On some OS you should use `echo -e` to make OS interpret `\n` as expected. Remember, you can always change default redis dilimited using `redis-cli -d <dilimiter>`

Comment: on CentOS, `echo -e "DEL 9012012\nDEL 1212" | redis-cli`

Comment: Or, if you're on bash: `redis-cli <<<$'DEL 9012012\nDEL 1212'`. You can also instead of `$''`, just use double quotes and actual new lines (i.e. not `\n`) to separate commands.

Answer (score 21):

The `redis-cli --pipe` can be used for mass-insertion. It is available since 2.6-RC4 and in Redis 2.4.14.
For example:

```
cat data.txt | redis-cli --pipe
```

More info in: http://redis.io/topics/mass-insert

Comment: If you want to execute multiple commands, e.g. select # and flushdb, then use ControlAltDel's solution because it won't work using the --pipe option.

Comment: // , Is there a way to use the `--pipe` option that would allow it to work for this question?

Comment: I was able to use the `--pipe` option to do a mass set of `EXPIRE` commands, so it works for things other than insertion.  Note: I had to make sure each command in the file was separate by both a carriage return _and_ a linefeed, not _just_ a linefeed.

Answer (score 12):

I know this is an old old thread, but adding this since it seems missed out among other answers, and one that works well for me.

Using [heredoc](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) works well here, if you don't want to use echo or explicitly add `\n` or create a new file -

```sh
redis-cli <<EOF
select 15
get a
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to place it here since I searched for my case and found this question along the way. I needed to execute redis multi-line command via npm scripts with variables to be parsed in redis commands (redis implemented as a Docker container).  To do so, I created txt named **redis-delete-key.txt** file with commands:

```
SELECT 1
DEL ${KEY}
```

where I choose desired redis db and remove the key.

In package.json I added the following command:

```
"scripts": {
  ...
  "delete-key-from-redis": "envsubst <redis-delete-key.txt | docker exec -i redis redis-cli"
}
```

where envsubst is linux command to replace variables in file.

To pass the variables I execute the npm command like this:

```
KEY="anykey" npm run delete-key-from-redis
```

Works for me, hope will be helpful for someone.