# Get results from redis-cli

Tags: powershell, batch-file, redis

1. I'm kinda new to writing batches and i'm trying to write one that connects to redis server in localhost, execute some commands and put the result in stdout (I need to analyze this result in other tool).

I've started with a simple `PING` command.
Here is the batch content:

```
redis-cli -h localhost -p 6379 PING>&1
```

I'm getting this error:

```
The handle could not be duplicated
during redirection of handle 1.
```

2. What should I do in case I have multiple commands like:
   `redis-cli -h localhost -p 6379 PING`
   `redis-cli -h localhost -p 6379 KEYS *`? Should I have to execute them separately ?
3. Is getting result from redis-cli is fine ? Or it's better to use PowerShell for this cases ?
   https://powerredis.codeplex.com/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10822877/executing-batches-of-commands-using-redis-cli have you seen this?

Comment: still stuck on the stdout thing. can't figure out what i'm doing wrong

Comment: i was able to output results into file, but I need them in stdout so that the other tool i'm using would get them