# redis: Create cluster with redis-cli non interactively

Tags: redis, redis-cli

When trying to create a cluster with `redis-cli` as follows

```
redis-cli --cluster create
```

a prompt comes up asking for configuration confirmation?

Is there a way to script this (preferably in `ansible`) and run it non-interactively?

I am aware of [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10822877/executing-batches-of-commands-using-redis-cli) however it addresses data manipulation which is not the scope of this question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`--cluster-yes` is the correct option!

Answer (score 10):

**EDIT:** 
The [answer of Leonardo Oliveira](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57191469/1578864) rightfully points out that the option `--cluster-yes` will avoid the prompt. For example:

```
redis-cli --cluster create host1:6379 host2:6379 host3:6379 --cluster-yes
```

---

<del>As of the current Redis version (5.0.5) there doesn't seem to be a flag under `--cluster` that can silence or auto-answer the interactive question:</del>

```
$ redis-cli --cluster help
Cluster Manager Commands:
  create         host1:port1 ... hostN:portN
                 --cluster-replicas <arg>
  check          host:port
                 --cluster-search-multiple-owners
  info           host:port
  fix            host:port
                 --cluster-search-multiple-owners
  reshard        host:port
                 --cluster-from <arg>
                 --cluster-to <arg>
                 --cluster-slots <arg>
                 --cluster-yes
                 --cluster-timeout <arg>
                 --cluster-pipeline <arg>
                 --cluster-replace
  rebalance      host:port
                 --cluster-weight <node1=w1...nodeN=wN>
                 --cluster-use-empty-masters
                 --cluster-timeout <arg>
                 --cluster-simulate
                 --cluster-pipeline <arg>
                 --cluster-threshold <arg>
                 --cluster-replace
  add-node       new_host:new_port existing_host:existing_port
                 --cluster-slave
                 --cluster-master-id <arg>
  del-node       host:port node_id
  call           host:port command arg arg .. arg
  set-timeout    host:port milliseconds
  import         host:port
                 --cluster-from <arg>
                 --cluster-copy
                 --cluster-replace
  help
```

---

By using `echo` you can execute the command and auto-answer the prompt:

```
echo "yes" | redis-cli --cluster create host1:6379 host2:6379 host3:6379
```

The default [Ansible Redis module](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/database/misc/redis.py) only supports a few commands and not `--cluster` so you would have to create your own logic with command/shell tasks:

```
- name: Create cluster
  shell: echo "yes" | redis-cli --cluster create host1:6379 host2:6379 host3:6379
  run_once: true
  when: not cluster_setup_done
```

Comment: Unrecognized option or bad number of args for: '--cluster'

Comment: this was an outdated redis-cli. 6.2.0 works fine - it says Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:7100: Connection refused

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know about the ansible part. But Redis [official site](https://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial) does provide a way to *create cluster with script in a little interactive-mode*.

**Creating a Redis Cluster using the create-cluster script** (Please refer docs for more details)

> If you don't want to create a Redis Cluster by configuring and executing individual instances manually as explained above, there is a much simpler system (but you'll not learn the same amount of operational details).
>
> Just check `utils/create-cluster` directory in the Redis distribution. There is a script called `create-cluster` inside (same name as the directory it is contained into), it's a simple bash script. In order to start a 6 nodes cluster with 3 masters and 3 slaves just type the following commands:
>
> ```
> create-cluster start
> create-cluster create
> ```
>
> Reply to yes in step 2 when the redis-cli utility wants you to accept the cluster layout.
>
> You can now interact with the cluster, the first node will start at port 30001 by default. When you are done, stop the cluster with:
>
> ```
> create-cluster stop
> ```
>
> Please read the README inside this directory for more information on how to run the script.

You can try implementing this if it helps you in any way!
Cheers :)